# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 when taking picture

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am working on an app that takes a picture and saves it to the device.  When clicking "save" it seems to take too long and it throws this message in the log:

```
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

Here is the method that's called when saving a picture taken:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    int img_count = [[appDelegate retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"image_saved"] intValue];
    img_count = img_count + 1;

    NSString *imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"dmg_image_%@_%d", [appDelegate retrieveFromUserDefaults:@"current_job_id"], img_count];

    [appDelegate saveImage:image withName:imageName];
    [appDelegate saveToUserDefaults:imageName key:@"inspection_image"];

    [damageImage setImage:image];
    [damageDesc becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, and I'm thinking that whatever is throwing this message is the cause for it running a little slow.

I have read the other people having this issue, but they are using an alert call, not a return from taking a picture.  Should I use a slight delay when calling didFinishPicking as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, presumably, that you're running this metho on the main thread. The `wait_fences` function is an internal function of one of the iOS graphics libraries, and it's related to animation -- when you're saving the image, you're blocking the main thread and the UI while writing a big amount of data to a file. Move the saving functionality to another thread (consider using `NSThread`) and your user interface should be responsive again.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes total sense.  Thanks so much!